# Are you supposed to include Gemfile.lock in a published gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

If you publish the source for a ruby gem to github.com, is the Gemfile.lock supposed to included?

Comment: Although it is not required, it can be handy for potential contributors to set up their development environment and run the specs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This guy has strong opinions.

http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/

Namely:

- You **should** include your Gemfile.lock in version control if you're developing an application
- You **should not** include your Gemfile.lock in version control if you're developing a gem

I'm not sure if I'm convinced yet.  I think that using the Gemfile.lock in my version control is good.  But I think that it is too much for that file to be included for others use.  The gemfile is enough for an install for others.  I think Gemfile.lock is for development, not deployment, contrary to the previously expressed opinion.

Comment: From the linked article: _check in your Gemfile.lock, since you will use the bundler tool across all machines_. To me that is deployment :)

Answer (score 2):

No, the `Gemfile.lock` file is an aid for deployment, not for development.

It is used to recreate an exact replica of your environment on another systems, something that is not (usually) required for development.